# Preg match full stop

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to run a preg_match on every file that contains a full stop with it.

```
<?php 

$furl = "Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3";

if (preg_match("/./i", $furl)) { 

echo "Contains full stop";

}

?>
```

Can someone please help???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternate and also fast then preg_match

```
if (strpos($furl, '.') !== false)
{
 echo "Contains full stop";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 

$furl = "Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3";

if (preg_match("/\./", $furl)) { 

echo "Contains full stop";

}

?>
```

In a regexp, '.' matches any character. If you want to limit it to a real '.', escape it with '\'.

You also don't need the /i, since there are no letters involved.

Answer (score 2):

`.` in regular expressions means "Match *anything*". Escape it thusly `\.`. (Though strpos is probably faster in this case)